# How to print out a dictionary whose value is a class

Tags: dictionary, printing

I am trying to create an ordering system, but I want a dictionary that prints out 2 value.  Food and price. I created a class with food and price and used that in the dictionary, but when I go to print it out only the name of the class is printed and not the values I assigned to the fields of the class

//*****Below is the simple code I wrote. This does not print out "Burger" and 5.50

```
       class Prices 
{
  public string food{ get; set; } 
  public double price { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
var Menu = new Dictionary<int, Prices>() 
{ 
  {1, new Prices{food = "Taco",price = 2.50} }, 
  {2, new Prices{food = "Burger",price= 5.50} }
};
 Menu.Add(3, new Prices { food = "Soda", price = 1.99 });//initializing by using Menu.Add
 Console.WriteLine("below is the name and cost for item 2:");
 Console.WriteLine(Menu[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the toString method in your class,

```
public String toString(){
   return food + " " + price
}
```

or something like that.

Comment: I ended up using a tuple.                                                                                      Dictionary<int, ValueTuple<string,int>> Menu = new Dictionary<int, ValueTuple<string, int>>()
            {
                {1, ValueTuple.Create<string, int>("Burger",  2)},
                {3, ValueTuple.Create<string, int>("t",3)  }
                

            };